# Redirect all traffic to root of another domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain that's not to be used anymore. I want to redirect all from `http://www.old.com/` to `http://www.new.com/`, no matter what page the user's attempted to access on `www.old.com`.

Doing this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / http://www.new.com/
```

is fine for the root, but other pages would do this:

`http://www.old.com/cms -> http://www.new.com/cms`

whereas I'd want it to go to the root, no matter what.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

From http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php I'd say you can use the following configuration

Don't redirect subfolders/files (as you wanted): www.example.com/demo/ -> www.newexampledomain.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Redirect to subfolders/files: www.example.com/demo/ -> www.newexampledomain.com/demo/

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And what about Virtualhost? If both domains are pointing to the same server what's the best choice? Default should be the new one plus use an alias for the old one like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16011435/4458531 ?

Comment: This still passes query variables. Add a single ? to the end to replace the query with nothing.

Answer (score 18):

Put this code in your ROOT .htaccess on `www.old.com`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This rule will externally redirect all `www.old.com/*` to `www.new.com/`

Comment: Thanks.  This was the solution that worked for me since I host multiple domains on the same root.