# Redirect to other domain, but keep original domain, except one folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that collects multiple dealers. Some of them have their own domains, so for them I need to redirect to my domain, but keep the typed domain in the address bar.

This one did that trick for me: [Redirect to other domain but keep typed domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain)

But the problem is that the redirecting is to a subfolder on my server, so `mydealer.com` will point to `mydomain.com/dealers/mydealer`, which causes all my static files to not load. They are located in a folder called `/static/`.

So is there a way to have `mydealer.com/anything/` to point to `mydomain.com/dealers/mydealer`, but have `mydealer.com/static/` to point to `mydomain.com/static/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to check if `/static/` is requested

```
RewriteEngine On

# for "static" part of dealers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [P]

# for dynamic part of dealers (/dealers/domain-dealer/*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/dealers/%2/$1 [P,NC]
```

Comment: Would this work for all redirects? Say I have `dealer2.com` pointing to `domain.com/dealers/dealer2` as well. Same for `dealer3.com` and so on.

Comment: Reading your comment, i think i misunderstood your initial question. Let's say you have your own site `domain.com`. In `/dealers/` folder, you have a folder for each dealers (domain name). When someone go to `free-dealer.com` (for example) you want it to load content of `domain.com/dealers/free-dealer/` while browser's url stays unchanged ? This means you have access to each dealers' server (and htaccess) right ?

Comment: Each dealer will point their domain to the main IP (for `domain.com`), yes. So the point is that browsing `free-dealer.com` should be exactly like browsing `domain.com/dealers/free-dealer`. The dealers only have domains, no servers, and that's why I need the requests for `free-dealer.com/static/*` to point to `domain.com/static/*`, while `free-dealer.com/*` points to `domain.com/dealers/free-dealer/*`

Comment: Ok i got it. One more thing before editing my answer. You said `dealers only have domains, no servers`. Which means those domains are pointing to the same document root on your main domain server ?

Comment: Right. You can see my edited answer about it. Don't forget to replace domain.com by your main domain. Should be working as expected (tested in my environnement and working). Tell me if something goes wrong on your side

Comment: We're waiting for the site to go live, so we can start testing the multiple domains. But I've set it up locally, and it looks like it's working. Thanks!