# How to rewrite url with a different domain in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, dns, url-rewriting

Hi I would like to rewrite my wordpress URL from

*www.myactivity.com*

to

*www.mysociety.com*

I have another domain (which is redirected to my wp site) named *www.mysociety.com*, which does not contain my web site, but only redirects to it.

However when people visit the web site I want them to see in the address bar the official domain *www.mysociety.com*

Thanks for helping!

Elena

Comment: So when someone visits myactivity.com it should redirect them to mysociety.com right. That is, no matter which url they use when the site loads you want the url in the address bar to show mysociety.com right?

Comment: Are those 2 domains under the same registrar (such as Go Daddy)?

Comment: Thanks for answering. @skribe yes you have understood my question and  yes the two domains are under the same registrar. I found a possible answer on stackoverflow at the following link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain) and I just have opened a ticket with my registrar to check what can I do. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to, or ask your host to, assign www.mysociety.com as your main domain. Then simply setup a redirect on your domain registrar myactivity.com to  your main site.

Comment: Thanks @skribe, I have checked with my host but it seems their server does not permit to do it. I used a simple redirect and keep the different address in the url bar