# .htaccess redirect + rewrite problems

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect `http://www.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com/public/plebs/` using the htaccess file.

But my problem is that I don't want the url's to look like this: `http://www.example.com/public/plebs/.example.php` but like this: `http://www.example.com/example.php`

Let me now if you could help me, thanks.

Comment: This may help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/plebs
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/plebs/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/plebs/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/plebs/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/plebs/$1 [L]
```

depending on how you've got your server setup.