# htaccess redirect url without chaging url in address bar

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hello i am using WordPress with WP-globus which is a translation plugin. I have two languages selected English and french. The plugin adds '/fr/' to the end of the domain to load the french content.

For example:

- xxxxxx refers to the post title.
- mysite.com/xxxxxx displays english version
- mysite.com/fr/xxxxxx - displays the french version

What i want is that when visitor go to mysite.fr/xxxxxx , it should load content of mysite.com/fr/xxxxxx.

Can anyone guide me with this. Can this be done using the htaccess?

Note: the url in address bar must not display mysite.com/fr/xxxxxx  but must display mysite.fr/xxxxxx

Comment: Please check this response and see if it helps in your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain

Comment: Thanks moshin but it was not of any help to me :(

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue, And working fine for me. Do some minor chnages in wpglobus plugin.

You have two different domains,both have pointing to same hosting right?

mysite.com

mysite.com.fr(load french content)

Here the solution,

Go to wpglobus plugin folder

inside the folder includes/**class-wpglobus-config.php** open and paste the following line after the mentioned line

```
public $extended_options = array(); after

protected $domain_french = 'mysite.com.fr'; //add this line  only
```

Next Find this function **init_current_language()**

end of this function add this line

```
if( stristr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $this->domain_french ) )
 $this->language    = 'fr';
```

Save the file.thats it.

Now your mysite.com.fr site loaded french content default.

Next you need to prevent adding /fr/ in french site.

same includes folder fine **class-wpglobus-utils.php** open it.

Find **function localize_url**

inside the function find this line

```
if ( ($language === $config->default_language && $config->hide_default_language))
```

to

```
if ( ($language === $config->default_language && $config->hide_default_language) || $language   ==='fr')
```

thats it. I hope this solution solve your problem.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct to me, you are editing a core file in the plugins folder. How can we over-ride the file in our own theme folder so we can make this change?