# Masking URL or Hiding external URL or redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, .htaccess, url

I'm looking for an answer to a problem I'm facing currently. Okay the problem is that A is my URL and B is a partnered URL. B has created us a website and this website we using for services, I have redirected A to go to B with .htaccess.

At the moment when a client type's A on the browser it goes to B site but the B's URL will stay on the browser, I don't want B's URL to show up on browser I want A to show on browser. How can I hide or mask B to A URL. Please note that A is sitting on a different server then B. How can I accomplish this I would really appreciate this someone that could help me.

Comment: I think that's what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16011316/3889043

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I think what you're referring to seems to be both of the websites sitting on the same server, not an external one. A is sitting on a different server then B.

Comment: I think it applies to another domain.

Comment: I tried adding that code on my cpanel with my URLs but, I still get the B URL showing up on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to fix this was, calling up the domain registrar in my case crazydomain. I asked them to do cloaking, they did it for me and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to route your url in .httaccess or in your route handling file.