# Redirect website but keep the original url in the address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

I have a local domain name **.dz** which **doesn't allow DNS changes**, I want to redirect the domain and all the pages to another domain **.com**, and keep the .dz address in the address bar and completely hide the .com domain.

I've searched the whole Internet all solutions doesn't do this, some does the redirect to .com and the .com shows in the address bar and some others redirect only the homepage.

I am wondering if the is a php function to read directly from the .com domain and then writes the content to the .dz domain

I have access to both .htaccess or the PHP files.

Comment: as I asked and hilighted, I can't change the DNS zone so I can't park my domain !

Comment: Do you have access to the server config? Or just `.htaccess`?

Comment: @w3dk .dz => htaccess /////// .com => everything

Comment: Check this answer: [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain)

Answer (score 8):

I assume you have access to [`httpd.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html) or `conf` directory,

Try this in your [`httpd.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html) in the section where mod_proxy is mentioned.

```
ProxyPass / http://yourwebsite.com/ smax=0 ttl=60 retry=5
ProxyPassReverse / http://yourwebsite.com/ smax=0 ttl=60 retry=5
```

And may be in case you have to put above rules in separate conf file named `httpd-ajp.conf` you will find it in `conf/extra` directory.

And when done you have to restart your server before attempting to check.

**Edit**

As you've said that you don't have access to `conf` directory you can try below rule in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [P]
```

But you must ensure that mod_proxy is enabled these lines must uncommented in `httpd.conf`, hoping you are able to ask it to your hosting provider.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: i don't have access to httpd.conf in the .dz domain

Answer (score 5):

Try with proxy in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,P]
```

It is possible that this is good enough in your case, if the site is simple.

Comment: I just tried with 2 of my servers, It works perfectly. (However, it does not work with proxy to https). In your case, I think the destination server is blocking or redirecting.

Comment: @Séddik What do you mean by "didn't work"? Any errors? `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` both need to be enabled on your source server (ie. `example.dz`). (_Aside:_ The `L` flag is not required here, `P` implies `L`.)

Comment: the .com website shows in the adressbar, tried with multiple browsers and also cleared the App Cache and tried incognito and private mode, no luck

Comment: @Séddik Are you proxying to the _canonical_ domain? Do you have any canonical redirects at your `.com` domain? ie. If you proxy to `example.com` and your `.com` site has a canonical redirect to `www.example.com`, then that will be your redirect. (?)

Answer (score 2):

in fact the web application should be hosted in **.dz** domain and you should redirect **.com** permanently to **dz.** what ever you do except changing DNS in dz domain side it's gonna be a request to **.com** not itself (the dz domain name).

I mean there is no way unless you want to map all urls and make a curl to **.com** for each request and change the DOM file and print it. or use Iframe which means you should keep **.com** domain also.

Comment: its the inverse, my application is hosted on the **.com**  and I want to redirect it to => **.dz**,
and for the iFrame solution is it SEO friendly ??!!

Comment: as you said "keep the .dz address in the address bar" you should 1) host application in dz and redirect com to it [301 redirect]. or 2) keep application in com and change .dz dns to .com ip and handle with domain alias in com.

about iframe and seo. definitely not. even keeping both sites are not a good solution because one is a copy of other one. and you should use 301 redirect

Comment: If I host my app on the .dz i won't need the .com, because the .dz is too slow and doesn't allow DNS change, that's why i've reserved a .com and I'want to redirect the "slow hosting" .dz to "the fast host ".com

Comment: there are two ways to bind domain to another host: domain owner can change it when ever he want by changing domain ns names (ns1 and ns2 and ...) and bind it as parked or alias domain in other host - or if it binds to a host with dns management you can make an A record on the host and add it to other host as parked or alias domain again. thats it.

Comment: Its obvious in my question that i don't have neither ways, please read my question first !

Answer (score 1):

There is a method so long as they are hosted separately, however, your .com will need to be live and working.

This is the same as the original Facebook apps system anything that is sent to its URL and then reads and presents the output. whether it's GET, POST or Headers

Basically, it's a PHP scripted proxy that does not change or add anything to the output from the service it's proxying

```
<?php 
$protocol = "http";
$domain = "domain.com";

$ch = curl_init();

$requestPath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$queryString = http_build_query($_GET);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $protocol.'://'.$domain.$requestPath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$mode = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$headers = getallheaders();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

if ($mode == 'POST'){
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count(http_build_query($_POST)));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

$headers = explode("\r\n", $header);
unset($headers[0]);
echo "<pre>";
foreach($headers as $val){
    if(strpos($val, "Transfer-Encoding") === false){
        header("$val");
        flush(); 
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $body;
?>
```

with a rewrite file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

if you host this on your .dz domain it will then point to your .com without changing the domain name.

Comment: ...this *seems* like it *might* be a helpful method but a little **more information** would be nice.  How is this used?  Would I use **both** the PHP code **and** put the other part into `.htaccess`?   What exactly is the code *doing*?  (also, please check out [answer].)

Comment: @ashleedawg please go read that How to Answer nowhere in there does it say to explain your code, and reading the code no one should use the code they can't read and understand because then you don't know what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

@Séddik,  Please try like this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.your-local-domain.dz


RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.your-another-domain.com/$1 [P]
```

This may helps you!

Comment: documentation please

Answer (score 0):

To show contents from DomainB but show DomainA url there are 2 options:

**1. Park domain**

If DomainB is your [primary domain name](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/amp/locate-primary-domain-name), just add DomainA as a [Parked Domain](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-manage-domains/park).

**2. Redirect Using .htaccess file**

This method is: Redirect and keep everything after the URL

The first option will show all of the same content on one URL as you would another.
To do this, you would modify your .htaccess file for the domain that your users will go to, and insert these lines of code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/$1 [P]
```

If you are using the [file manager in cPanel](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-file-manager/using-file-manager-in-cpanel), be sure that you have the option to show hidden files selected.

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned - 'the .dz is too slow and doesn't allow DNS change, that's why i've reserved a .com and I'want to redirect the "slow hosting" .dz to "the fast host ".com'..

When the .dz domain is too slow, it is not worth to invest your time on the redirection of the entire web traffic. It will make things more slower.

You can put a re-direction html (like meta-refresh) in your slow hosting .dz domain and serves the users directly from the .com domain. There is no way you will benefit from keeping the 'slow hosting' .dz domain as your main site...

Answer (score -1):

This code shall help you redirect and keep everything after the URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.com    

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domainname.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: What domain goes where? Documentation?