# .htaccess rewrite subdomain keeps original url

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I am writing a .htaccess rule that sends a subdomain request to a specific login page file. My current rule is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.name.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://name.com/app/login [R=302,L,NE]
```

This works as I would expect. I now want to build on this so as to keep the original url displayed. The RewriteRule would continue to redirect to https://name.com/app/login but still display https://subdomain.name.com as the URL within the web browser.

Is this possible within .htacess file? I cannot find a solution.

Comment: You want either an internal redirect (if both are on the same machine, and the general setup of the domains allows for it), or you would have to _proxy_ the request ( `P` flag in RewriteRule, needs mod_proxy enabled.)

Comment: Yes both are on the same machine. How would I change the above for it to be treated as an internal redirect?

Comment: You would need to specify a relative URL, and remove the `R` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.name.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://name.com/app/login [P]
```

For this to work, you need to

1) enable [apache proxy module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)

2) enable **SSLProxyEngine** in the [VirtualHost definition](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html):

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.name.com:80>
    ...
    SSLProxyEngine on
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost subdomain.name.com:443>
    ...
    SSLProxyEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

3) If the certificate is not "trusted", e.g. is self signed, you could disable the proxy `s verification by adding:

```
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```

to the virtualHost definitions above.

### References

- [Redirect website but keep the original url in the address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41376135/4448410)
- [Disable proxy ssl verification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22069646/4448410)