# Retain URL in browser with Flask redirect

Tags: nginx, heroku, flask, bokeh, nginx-config

I have a Bokeh server application deployed on Heroku, with multiple styles that result in cumbersome URLs. For example: https://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com/avyview?style=snowpacktracker

I am using Flask deployed on Heroku to take extensions from a simple custom domain ([www.snowpacktracker.com](http://www.snowpacktracker.com)) and redirect to a second Heroku app that runs a Bokeh server and returns the html content. The relevant Flask app code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return redirect(url_for("btac"), code=302)

@app.route('/btac')
def func1():
  return redirect("https://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com/avyview?style=snowpacktracker", code=302)

@app.route('/btac/historic') 
def btac_historic():
  return redirect("https://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com/avyview", code=302)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

I would like the original URL to remain the same while the Flask redirect occurs. Is there an option within Flask to do this? Or can I configure the web server to accomplish this?

**UPDATE and further details:**

I cannot get the nginx proxying to work correctly. My current situation:

[www.snowpacktracker.com](http://www.snowpacktracker.com) is setup as a custom domain (using a Heroku-provided DNS target) for my Heroku app that is running nginx + gunicorn + Flask (this is a working link you can use to see the current behavior). The underlying URL for this Heroku app is https://snowpacktracker.herokuapp.com.

When this first Heroku app receives a request, the Flask app redirects to a second Heroku app running a Bokeh server. As currently implemented, you can see the URL switch in the browser to https://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com/avyview?style=snowpacktracker.

Both [www.snowpacktracker.com](http://www.snowpacktracker.com) and [www.snowpacktracker.com/btac](http://www.snowpacktracker.com/btac) redirect to the same URL. I have a second style defined with [www.snowpacktracker.com/btac/historic](http://www.snowpacktracker.com/btac/historic) that redirects to https://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com/avyview.

**My goal is for a page load of [www.snowpacktracker.com](http://www.snowpacktracker.com) (and any extensions: /btac or /btac/historic) to redirect via Flask as is currently implemented, but for the original URL to remain unchanged.**

I have been trying to edit the `location` block in the `nginx.conf.erb` config file according to the link in the answer from @Fian, but I am having no luck.

What are the correct statements for `proxy_pass` or `proxy_redirect` (or `rewrite`?) in the `location` block to accomplish this desired behavior?

My current nginx config file (provided in the [Heroku nginx build pack](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack/blob/master/config/nginx.conf.erb)):

```
daemon off;
#Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_min_length 512;

    server_tokens off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;
    error_log logs/nginx/error.log;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    #Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your "relevant flask code" looks a bit redundant, as the whole thing can easily be implemented in nginx alone, without the need for the flask code you provide.

Something like this may work:

```
server_name .snowpacktracker.com;
location = / {
    return 302 /btac;
}
location / {
    return 404;
}
location /static {
    proxy_pass http://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com;
}
location /avyview {
    proxy_pass http://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com;
}
location = /btac {
    proxy_pass http://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com/avyview?style=snowpacktracker;
}
location = /btac/historic {
    proxy_pass http://invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com/avyview;
}
```

Note that your underlying app, at `invlabs-bokehserver.herokuapp.com/avyview`, explicitly mentions its own full URL in several instances, including for automatic JavaScript-based redirect to the mobile version (i.e., `window.location = 'https://btac-web-plots.herokuapp.com/avyview?style=snowpacktracker-mobile';`); this will obviously interfere with your desire to "hide" the underlying URL of the application.

Comment: I agree, there is really no reason for the Flask redirect. We have now started down the road suggested by @Fian, "revise your whole architecture". This involves embedding a server document from Bokeh into a Flask template, rather than redirecting to our fully rendered Bokeh document. However, I will use the approach you suggest should we need to rely on our original URL structure.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called proxying and can be achieved via [nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url) or [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain).

P.S. Your whole problem seems quite strange, please revise your whole architecture.

Comment: Thanks I will check out the proxying. I am using nginx + gunicorn on Heroku. Yes, this is actually a temporary workaround solution, leveraging a large amount of code we already have written. Although our architecture could use a major revision, time and funding are lacking.

Comment: I have been trying to edit the nginx config file, but not getting anywhere. I posted an update and further details with the default `location` block from my config file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding what http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect does.  It is apparent that you're trying to set it to `off` in an attempt to avoid user-facing redirects, e.g., `301` and `302 Moved`, from being given back to the user, revealing the internal domain names, but that's exactly the opposite of what the directive does — it is almost always best to leave it at defaults.

If you want the URL to remain unchanged, just use http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass.

Comment: Can you suggest something more specific for the `location` block? I have been trying various arguments for `proxy_pass`, but having no success.

Comment: What you have in your original question looks reasonable.  You may want to try removing the `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` part — unless your upstream indeed expects the hostname from the downstream.