# .htaccess specific url redirect to another domain url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have one domain but I want to use a specific url to another domain which is S3 host.

My needs :

`www.azerty.com/xyz` must use this url `http://xyz.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz`. But at the difference of url rewriting, I don't want that url change in navigator, just stay www.azerty.com/xyz.

How can I do this ?

I already try to update .htaccess like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.azerty.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xyz$    
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://xyz.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `mod-proxy` . https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html or see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not very familiar with this. I try this but doesn't work `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.azerty\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://xyz.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]`