# 301 redirect to new domain without changing URL?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm currently working on an Apache 301 redirect from one domain to another:

```
https://www.foo.com  -----> https://www.bar.com
```

A question I have is: does a solution exist where I can redirect the first domain to the second domain, but have the URL still display the original url?

My current rewrite rule is as follows and works perfectly for the intended solution, but the URL does change:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bar.com [R=301,L,NC]
```

Is there a modification I can make to achieve this functionality?  A question was raise and I'm not quite sure if this is possible, as I have never handled something like this in the past.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The only solution would be to set up whatever is hosting www.foo.com as a proxy to www.bar.com. There is no way to redirect the client in such a way that the URL remains the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to other domain but keep typed domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain)