# How can I hide url redirection?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, navigation

I am trying to redirect an old domain to a new one using ".htaccess" but it doesn't work.
I'd like to do something like :

```
 olddomain.com
```

to

```
 newdomain.mycompany.com
```

The redirection works but I'd like to keep the old domain name.
Someone can tell me what to write in the htaccess file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to other domain but keep typed domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [mod-proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) . If this module is enabled on your server you can use `P` flag in `RewriteRule` to proxy requests between two domains.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example2.com/$1 [P]
```

This will make an invisible redirection from `example1.com` to `example2.com` .