# How can I direct all traffic from a certain domain to any (future) page away using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, block, ref

Lets say you have "domain X" and "domain A"

"Domain A" is my domain, but I don't want ANY traffic when they have first visited "domain X".
So I need to do a ref check, and redirect all incoming traffic from "domain X" to something else (Best would be a forbidden page or alike, otherwise something like google works fine for me)

But I have no clue on how to code exactly the above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect all traffic to root of another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819706/redirect-all-traffic-to-root-of-another-domain)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for