# How to redirect https://olddomain.com to https://newdomain.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Our site name has changed and we have an ssl for both domains.  However all the links from the old site are not redirecting for example:

https://olddomain.com/productA does not redirect to https://newdomain.com/productA

It shows the old site with no styles to it.

If you go to https://oldomain.com it redirects just fine to https://newdomain.com

This is what the .htaccess file contains (some was generated from Cpanel, if I redirect a specific page it works fine)

```
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^928shopper\.com$ [OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.928shopper\.com$
# RewriteRule ^lake\-havasu\-city\-restaurants\-guide\/$ "https\:\/\/shophalfoff\.com\/lake\-havasu\-city\-restaurants\-guide\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^928shopper\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.928shopper\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://shophalfoff.com/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect all traffic to root of another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819706/redirect-all-traffic-to-root-of-another-domain)

Comment: I tried that solution, but it did not work. Sigh.

Comment: @TaraSamons what did you try? We can't tell because you didn't post your code as needed when asking a question. So we have nothing to suggest without it. Edit your question and post your current code