# .htaccess rewrite not rewriting bookmarked links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a client that purchased their original domain (.net) and then bought the .com domain as well, then asked me to redirect all traffic to the .com site, everything seemed to go according to plan... until I noticed if I had a page bookmarked, or typed the entire URL with the .net extension, the address would *not* rewrite to .com.

Example: if I navigate to `example.net/page` I want the address to change to `example.com/page` (whereas at the moment it is not)

Here's my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^promotionstudios\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.promotionstudios\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.promotionstudios\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Any insight is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you show just redirects the root directory (= literal calls to www.promotionstudios.net). For a solution that redirects *all* traffic, Google `htaccess redirect all traffic`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all traffic to root of another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819706/redirect-all-traffic-to-root-of-another-domain)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?promotionstudios\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.promotionstudios.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Better option than using htaccess is Domain Forwarding

> Note: According to service provider option names may differ. But it will be surely there.

Login to your .net `Domain Account` and select your .net domain.

> Under Domain Forwarding--> Manage Domain Forwarding
>   [image]

Make sure

```
URL Masking: OFF (if this is ON,example.com/page will be shown with example.net/page as url in the browser)
Sub Domain Forwarding: ON  (in case if you need your subdomains forwarded)
Path Forwarding: ON  (this will forward example.net/page to example.com/page)
```

Then save.

Next

> Under Domain Forwarding-->Name Server Details
>   [image]

From here you will get the Name Server details.

Next

> Under Domain Registration-->Name Servers

Fill the Name Server details got before and click Update Name Servers.

Now you are done.

> Note:These changes may require 24–72 hours to take effect