# Redirect traffic from a test site to the normal one

Tags: redirect, seo

2 weeks ago I assume a new project for Search Engine Optimisation.
Lately, I realize that the developer was in charge before has created **a test site which is live**. The result of this situation is the test site has much **better SEO and more traffic than the normal one**.

So my question is what should I make:
Should I **redirect every page** of the test site to the normal? and how!
Should he just **delete the test site**?

What I am thinking and please suggest me if this right or wrong, is:
Google now crawl the test site which looks like the original because created first and then crawl the normal site which looks like is duplicate site and they give it penalties.
So if I delete the test site Google crawler will crawl normal site as the original, right?
Of course, if there is a way to redirect all the traffic to normal one and increase the SEO Score would be awesome.
Hope my question is clear enough. I 'll appreciate any suggestion!
The resources I have found but doesn't solve my problem are: 
http://www.webconfs.com/154/301-redirects-how-to-redirect-your-website/ 
[Redirect all traffic to root of another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819706/redirect-all-traffic-to-root-of-another-domain)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I thought that using the right tags question is ok but I am sorry if it is out of topic.

Comment: It's not a matter of the right tags, it's a matter of the **wrong site**. [There is a warning about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334713/2370483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1) **Block test site for Crawling ASAP**.

- 1.1 Here is the simple code you need to add on robots.txt

  > User-agent: *
  >   Disallow: /
- 1.2 Now, you need to redirect all test site URL to normal site. 
  (In this option, your Test site traffic convert to Normal site)

2) Take backup and **delete your test site**

- Currently, Google have your Test site, so you need to fetch normal site in Google. after few time Google algorithm crawls normal site, they can start give priority to Normal site.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thanks a lot for your answer, appreciated!What If I just delete the test site?(Just I am not a specialist to redirect the test site but I think I figure it out.)

Comment: Hi Eleni,
If you delete the test site then you need to fetch normal site in Google. after few time Google algorithm crawls the normal site, they can start giving priority to the Normal site. But in this case, traffic will not redirect from test site to normal site.

Comment: Very useful your explanation, thanks Pankaj.